# Mathematical Logic: Propositional Logic; First Order Logic.

Tags: reference-request, logic, propositional-calculus

I need good book of Mathematical Logic for gate 2014 exam. 
GATE syllabus is "Mathematical Logic: Propositional Logic; First Order Logic".
Thank you.

Comment: that is a very complicated questions there are many ways to do logic and it does depend on the system that is used to test you. Can you give more information on the test. Do you mean the Indian State test Graduate Aptitude Test in Engineering 2014 for  Computer Science and Information Technology (CS) or do you mean another?

Comment: Take a look at  https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~vddries/main.pdf, it is a helpful source for mathematical logic.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming this is the Indian State test Graduate Aptitude Test in Engineering 2014 for Computer Science and Information Technology.

It is, frankly, quite unprofessional for the organising body to give as the syllabus "Mathematical Logic: Propositional Logic; First Order Logic". That gives no idea at all about how far you need to go.

Googling a past paper out of curiosity is a somewhat depressing experience. But the questions are brief multiple choice questions, and it seems you only need to know some basics (e.g. what a truth-truth table is, how to use the language of first-order logic). So any available text covering elementary logic should do -- especially, I suppose, if has a computer science slant. Read to the point where you can answer any question in papers for the last few years. (And if you possibly can, look at a few other texts briefly, to alert yourself to variations in notation and terminology -- as the questions set are unhelpful in this regard.)

For freely available online material, I'd mention [Paul Teller's *A Modern Formal Logic Primer*](http://tellerprimer.ucdavis.edu) as being particularly helpful to beginners on the translation of ordinary language in and out of the language of FOL.